# Bash: ls * without folder grouping

Tags: linux, ls

If I type:

```
ls source/*

source/fonts:
fontello

source/images:
bg1.png                eng.png        fra.png
```

I get the list of files, grouped by folder names.
How can I simply get the list of file names?

```
ls source/*

source/fonts/fontello
source/images/bg1.png
source/images/eng.png
source/images/fra.png
```

THanks

Comment: If this is for scripting use, you might want to see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. (That said, there are ways to use `find` wrong as well; particularly, if you're running `for file in $(find ...)`, you've hit one one of them).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doesn't seems to be possible without output alteration, but here is an easy alternative way:

```
find source/ -type f
```

Or (specific to GNU find), to only get files at the depth in your question:

```
find source/ -type f -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2
```

(or if you want directories like `ls` gives you, remove `-type f`)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply stick to ls if you add some psychedlics (`ls -d`):

```
# mkdir test
# cd test
# mkdir A B C
# touch {A,B,C}/file*
# ls -d */*    
A/file  B/file  C/file
```

Comment: @Cthulhu ok my example is too short, If you have folders in A,B a/o C the -d helps to display only what you selected. I actually don't like find and you can define the depth by the argument with ls -d

Comment: I've suggested an edit to the other answer to limit the depth.

Comment: @o11c very good, but still `find` is a fat beast.

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in “the poor man’s `find`”:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

`shopt -s` **s**ets the named shell option(s). 
The **`globstar`** option is defined as follows in [bash(1)](http://dell9.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?bash):

> If set, the pattern `**` used in a filename/pathname expansion context
>   will match a files <sub>[sic]</sub> and
>   zero or more directories and subdirectories. 
>   If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

So, after you’ve done `shopt -s globstar`, any of the following commands:

```
ls -d1 -- source/**                 # The character after the ‘d’ is the digit one.
ls -d -- source/** | cat            # i.e., it will write that into a pipe to any command.
printf "%s\n" source/**
```

will produce the output:

```
source/
source/fonts
source/fonts/fontello
source/images
source/images/bg1.png
source/images/eng.png
source/images/fra.png
```

Unfortunately, this includes the directory names, too. 
It might help you *a little* to know that

```
printf "%s\n" source/**/
```

will produce the output:

```
source/
source/fonts
source/images
```

i.e., *only* the directory names. 
You might redirect the output of one of the first set of commands to one file,
redirect the output of the above to a second file,
and then use `comm`, `diff`, or something similar,
to subtract the second file from the first,
leaving only the plain files (non-directories).  But [***don’t do that.***](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Another approach (that’s not *much* better) is

```
ls -d --file-type -- source/** | grep -v '/$'
```

The `--file-type` option tells `ls` to display a `/`
at the end of each directory name
(and other characters at the ends of other (special) file types), like this:

```
source//                            # Added an extra one
source/fonts/                       # Added one
source/fonts/fontello
source/images/                      # Added one
source/images/bg1.png
source/images/eng.png
source/images/fra.png
```

and then the `grep -v '/$'` removes the lines that end with `/`;
i.e., the directory names. 
Unfortunately, the `--file-type` option is not [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html). 
If your version of `ls` doesn’t support it, use `-F`. 
That is like `--file-type`
except it also displays a `*` at the ends of the names of executable files,
which some people find annoying. 
You can eliminate them with `sed`:

```
ls -dF -- source/** | sed -e '/\/$/d' -e 's/\*$//'
```

If you want to do something with all the files (and only the files), you can do

```
for f in source/**
do
    if [ -f "$f" ]
    then
        Insert commands to be applied to plain files here.
    fi
done
```

---

#### Notes:

- When `ls` is outputting to a terminal, and it’s not in `-l` (**l**ong) mode,
  it writes multiple names per line (unless the names are very long). 
  You can force it to write one name per line by specifying `-1` (one),
  or by redirecting output to a file or a pipe.
- You probably don’t really need the `--` in the `ls` commands
  since you’re listing a directory whose contents you created. 
  You should use it when listing `*` in an unknown directory,
  as protection against filenames that begin with `-`.
- [Don’t try to parse the output from `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- The `globstar` shell option appears not to be defined by POSIX. 
  (In fact, I’m not sure POSIX recognizes *any* shell options.) 
  While it seems to be a `bash`ism, beware —
  it might not be present in all versions of bash.
- If `fonts` or `images` has subdirectories, `**` will list them all,
  recursively, all the way down. 
  One (somewhat kludgy and unreliable) way to limit the depth is

  ```
  ls -d --file-type -- source/** | grep -v '\(/.*\)\{3\}'
  ```

  which removes lines containing three or more `/` characters.